# Grunt build failing

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, gruntjs

I'm trying to build my angularjs project but i keep getting this error. I have searched for a solution but could not find one. How can i fix this error?

Thanks.

**Error message**

```
"/usr/local/bin/grunt" "clean"
>> Local Npm module "grunt-aws" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-connect" not found. Is it installed?
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Unable to read ".aws.json" file (Error code: ENOENT).
>> No "clean" targets found.
Warning: Task "clean" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to post-install your missing dependencies before your script launches on AWS.

Try adding in your `package.json` the following:

```
"scripts": { "postinstall": "npm install" }
```

Or simply run `npm install grunt-aws grunt-contrib-connect ...` before starting your app.